# Ngrx: Property '[Symbol.observable]' is missing in type 'Store<boolean>' error

Tags: typescript, ngrx, strictnullchecks

I'm using NGRX v4.1.1 in an Angular v5 app (with `"strictNullChecks": true`, though it doesn't appear to matter).

I'm seeing an error with the store. Given the following:

```
showLists: Observable<boolean>;

constructor(private store: Store<State>) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.showLists = this.store.select('contactsFeature', 'contactsReducer', 'showListsPanel');
}
```

Typescript is raising an error on `this.store.select()`:

```
Type 'Store<boolean>' cannot be converted to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
Property '[Symbol.observable]' is missing in type 'Store<boolean>'.
```

This method of selecting a slice of the store (using `.select`) and assigning it to a variable of type `Observable<>` is [officially outlined in the documentation](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/8c8b914eba166a364c640038b656e835d35cde15/docs/store/README.md) (I actually see they've updated the documentation to the ngrx v5 recommended API, but v5 hasn't been released yet, so I've linked to the next most recent version of the docs).

The problem is that `store.select()` has a return type of `Store<>` which is incompatible with `Observable<>`.

This is the 'official' method of interacting with the Store however (I think). So I'm wondering what's going wrong. If I disable `strictNullChecks`, I still run into the error. The error has popped up in a project I'm coming back to after a month away, and I can't determine when, exactly, it started (or why, obviously).

Any suggestions are appreciated :)

PS: Typescript will *not* let me cast the return of `.select()` to an observable.

### Update

Updating npm provided me with a better error message. It looks like either rxjs's interface has been updated, or perhaps ngrx's has.

```
ERROR in apps/coordination/src/app/contacts/contacts-tools.component.ts(21,5): error TS2322: Type 'Store<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
  Types of property 'subscribe' are incompatible.
    Type '{ (observer?: NextObserver<boolean> | ErrorObserver<boolean> | CompletionObserver<boolean> | unde...' is not assignable to type '{ (observer: Observer<boolean>): Subscription; (onNext: (value: boolean) => void, onError?: ((err...'.
      Types of parameters 'observer' and 'observer' are incompatible.
        Type 'Observer<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'NextObserver<boolean> | ErrorObserver<boolean> | CompletionObserver<boolean> | undefined'.
          Type 'Observer<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'CompletionObserver<boolean>'.
            Types of property 'complete' are incompatible.
              Type '(() => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
                Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using vscode with automatic module imports. i.e. if I make use of a class from an npm module, vscode will automatically add the proper `import` statement to the top of the file.

Apparently one of my npm modules (not rxjs) defined its own `Observable`, and vscode had automatically imported that, non-rxjs observable. This non-rxjs observable was causing the type problem.

Comment: This was exactly my issue! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure how your reducers looks like, but i assume that:

contactsFeature -> reducer
contactsReducer -> is attribute in contactsFeature
showListsPanel -> is attribute in contactsReducer object

You can use .select('reducer', 'atribute', 'sub'... ) instead of plucking ( .pluck ).

for other question, you can cast select with:

```
this.showLists = this.store.select('contactsFeature', 'contactsReducer', 'showListsPanel') as Observable<boolean>;
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "You can use .select('reducer', 'atribute', 'sub'... ) instead of plucking ( .pluck )."? I'm currently using `.select`, and I'm not familiar with the `.pluck()` method. Regarding "you can cast select with," sorry, I added a PS but could have been more clear: I tried casting to an observable, typescript won't let me. Says `Store<boolean>` doesn't support the `Observable<boolean>` interface or some such. Basically the same thing as the compilation error message.

Comment: Hmm, I created a new, test project and I have no problem with `this.showLists = this.store.select('contactsFeature', 'contactsReducer', 'showListsPanel');`. Something in my app must be changing `Store<>`...

Comment: Can you give me name of your reducer, name of property in that reducer you want to select?

Comment: Thanks for offering to help! I figured out the problem though (see my answer). I'm not allowed to mark my own answer as correct for another 2 hours though :/